# How to do async operation within async operation with CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, asynchronous

My goal is to do X operations in one go. I make a quick example, fetch the Car's rating. Each fetch will simulate a 100 delay. In theory, if we do synchronous fetch, it will take 1s to fetch 10 car with the car's rating. So, to make it faster, we need to use asynchronous operation.

**My expected result:**
If the synchronous version took 600ms to fetch 3 cars with the car's rating, then the asynchronous version should take less time. In best scenario 200ms (100ms to fetch the car basic details, 100ms to fetch the car's rating, regardless of how many cars' rating we fetch).

**My actual result:**
The asynchronous does take less time but in theory it have too many unnecessary loop to convert `List<CompletableFuture<Car>>` to `List<Car>` and sort of hacky way to chain stage.

This three code down below is used by the synchronous and asynchronous version.

Car

```
package comparison;

public class Car {
  int id;
  String name;
  double rating;

  public Car(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Car{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", rating=" + rating +
            '}';
  }
}
```

CarRating

```
package comparison;

public class CarRating {
  int id;
  int rating;

  public CarRating(int id, int rating) {
    this.id = id;
    this.rating = rating;
  }
}
```

FakeDatabase

```
package comparison;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FakeDatabase {
  static List<Car> tableCars = new ArrayList<>();

  static {
    tableCars.add(new Car(1, "Fiesta"));
    tableCars.add(new Car(2,  "Camry"));
    tableCars.add(new Car(3,  "M2"));
  }

  static List<CarRating> tableCarRatings = new ArrayList<>();

  static {
    tableCarRatings.add(new CarRating(1, 7));
    tableCarRatings.add(new CarRating(2, 4));
    tableCarRatings.add(new CarRating(2, 6));
    tableCarRatings.add(new CarRating(3, 8));
    tableCarRatings.add(new CarRating(3, 10));
    tableCarRatings.add(new CarRating(3, 6));
  }

  static List<Car> fetchCars() {
    simulateDelay();
    return tableCars;
  }

  static double fetchRating(int manufacturerId) {
    simulateDelay();
    return tableCarRatings
            .stream()
            .filter(carRating -> carRating.id == manufacturerId)
            .mapToInt(carRating -> carRating.rating)
            .average()
            .orElse(0);
  }

  static void simulateDelay() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
    }
  }

}
```

Synchronous version

```
public class SynchronousExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    List<Car> cars = fetchCars();
    cars.forEach(car -> {
      car.rating = fetchRating(car.id);
    });

    cars.forEach(System.out::println);

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Took " + (end - start) + "ms");
  }
}
```

It took 600ms to fetch 3 cars

1. fecthCars(); 100ms.
2. fetchRating(car.id); 100ms each.

Asynchronous First version

```
package comparison;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static comparison.FakeDatabase.fetchCars;
import static comparison.FakeDatabase.fetchRating;

public class AsynchronousExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    List<CompletableFuture<Car>> futures = fetchCars()
            .stream()
            .map(car -> {
              return CompletableFuture
                      .supplyAsync(() -> {
                        System.out.println("fetching id:\t" + car.id);
                        car.rating = fetchRating(car.id);
                        return car;
                      });
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    CompletableFuture
            .allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]))
            .whenComplete((cars, cause) -> {
              if (cause == null) {
                List<Car> updatedCars = futures.stream().map(future -> future.join()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                updatedCars.forEach(System.out::println);
              } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(cause);
              }
            })
            .join();

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Took " + (end - start) + "ms");

  }
}
```

It took 400ms to fetch 3 cars.

1. getCarAsync() simulate 100ms.
2. fetchRating(car.manufacturerId) simulate 100ms for each car.

However, it return `List<CompletableFuture<Car>>` instead of `CompletableFuture<List<Car>>`. It also not very useful because the `join()` return `Void` instead of `List<Car>`. I guess, `allOf()` is not the right choice.

Asynchronous Second version

```
package comparison;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static comparison.FakeDatabase.fetchCars;
import static comparison.FakeDatabase.fetchRating;

public class AsynchronousExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    List<CompletableFuture<Car>> futures = fetchCars()
            .stream()
            .map(car -> {
              return CompletableFuture
                      .supplyAsync(() -> {
                        System.out.println("fetching id:\t" + car.id);
                        car.rating = fetchRating(car.id);
                        return car;
                      });
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    CompletableFuture<List<Car>> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();

    CompletableFuture
            .allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]))
            .whenComplete((cars, ex) -> {
              if (ex == null) {
                cf.complete(futures.stream().map(future -> future.join()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
              } else {
                cf.completeExceptionally(ex);
              }
            });

    cf.join().forEach(System.out::println);

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Took " + (end - start) + "ms");

  }
}
```

This version took 500ms. And achieve what I want `cf.join()` to get `List<Car>`. However, it's not readable. The `CompletableFuture<List<Car>> cf` depends on `allOf()` which will invoke `cf.complete(features.stream().map(future -> future.join()).collect(Collectors.toList()))` in case there is no issue, if there is exception, I need to do sort of hack again `cf.completeExceptionally(ex)`. And, i believe this violate the chaining stages pattern.

This is my second day learning CompletableFuture, so I have not grasped the entire idea yet.

Comment: Your time calculations seem to be assuming you have unlimited bandwidth to make multiple requests in parallel, and the database you are retrieving from is able to handle multiple concurrent requests each within the same execution time as a single request. One or both of these is probably not true :-)

Comment: @KevinHooke it's just for study material. The point is to design a `async operation within async operation` and then get the result with `get()`.

Comment: You've got the basics covered. My point was that you've overthinking the time calculation with a locally simulated/mock db because in reality there's too many other factors that will affect the time to complete the requests to a remote db if you hit it with multiple requests at the same time. e.g. if one request takes 100ms, 10 requests at the same time will not all complete within 100ms.

Comment: @KevinHooke you're right. I think I chose wrong example as it leads to misconception. I will try to re-design it tonight.